# ObjectInputStream hangs both server and client even after flushing

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, objectinputstream

I've written a basic TCP chat in Java and when testing locally (i.e. localhost) it's been working fine. I can connect, type messages to myself and receive without issues. I can connect and disconnect several times a second.

However, when trying to connect through my router's external IP for whatever reason it hangs when trying to initialize the ObjectInputStream on not only the Client side, but also Server side. So I'm guessing it's something to do with my Router firewall, on which I added a firewall rule. I did only create a firewall rule for the specific port 1777 where I make my connection, is it possible that the data sent when flushing ObjectOutputStream is sent on another port? Which wouldn't make sense I guess considering the socket is bound to a specific port.

I am flushing after initializing the ObjectOutputStream and I am creating that before creating the ObjectInputStream, on both sides. What doesn't make sense to me is that it allows for a connection to be made.

I guess code may be irrelevant in this case, but here it is anyway:

This Thread is run at all times, and waits for connections then starts a new Thread for handling the connecting client:

```
public void run() {
    while (connected) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new ClientHandler(socket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Constructor of ClientHandler class:

```
public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    welcomeClient();
    start(); // Start listening for messages.
}
```

This is where the ClientHandler Thread hangs.

Here is Client side code:

```
// Get IP, port and stuff
socket = new Socket(ip, port);
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outputStream.flush();
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
// Write a couple objects and read some objects.
```

They both hang on "inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());"

What could be the problem? I can also connect through my local IP, which makes me think it's still an outbound->inbound firewall issue for whatever reason.

Comment: If you suspect your firewall of interfering, then it seems logical to check its logs.  That should tell you whether it has blocked traffic involved in your system, and if it has, it should give you a pretty good idea of why.

Comment: Nevermind! It seems I can't connect to my own router from inside the network. When a friend tried to connect from his network, it worked perfectly :-) Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: You should create the streams in the `run()` method, not the constructor, so it happens on the new thread and doesn't mess up the accept loop.